# Is everything allright about this program?

Tags: c

## The problem is -

> *Write a C function that calculates the value of weight **z** subject to the following conditons --*
>
> z = x^2 - 4*y if ( x > y)
>
> z = x^2 + 4*y if ( x < y)
>
> z = ( x + y )^3/4 if ( x = y )
>
> *Then write a C main program that reads the values for **x** and **y** and calls the developed function for calculating the value of weight **z***.

Is the program perfect for every possible input that will be given ? Here is an repl.it version - https://repl.it/J0ev/0

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float calc( float val1, float val2 ) ;
int main(void)
{
  float x, y, z ;
  printf("Enter x - ") ;
  scanf("%f", &x ) ;
  printf("Enter y - " ) ;
  scanf("%f", &y ) ;
  z = calc( x , y ) ;
  printf("Value of z is - %.2f", z ) ;
  return 0 ;
}
float calc ( float val1, float val2 )
{
  float result ;
  if (val1 > val2 )
      result = pow( val1 , 2 ) - 4*val2 ;
  else if ( val1 < val2 )
      result = pow( val1 , 2 ) + 4*val2 ;
  else if ( val1 == val2 )
      result = pow( val1 + val2 , 3/4 ) ;
  return result ;
}
```

I think  there is a logical error in the implementation of *val1==val2*.

N.B. - I'm a beginner in programming or coding .

Comment: you could start by dropping `else if ( val1 == val2 )` for just `else`, since it's the only case left, and you will avoid floating point equality error.

Comment: Yes, there is. Exact comparison is usually not working with `float`s. Just remove the `else if` and let it be `else`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That won’t change anything.

Comment: `3/4` --> `3./4`

Comment: Yes, indeed: there's a logical error in the implementation of `val1 == val2`. Write a simple program that shows you the value of `3/4`.

Comment: @Ryan You are right. Op should be prepared to the fact that this case might never hit.

Comment: Wea are not a code verification service. Ask your teacher.

Comment: I suggest you use `double` not `float` unless there is a very good reason not too. And using `float` suggests you are using a 20th centry textbook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for a [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @Olaf I have a shitty prof and I can't do anything about it . Most of what I learn is self-taught .

Comment: @FahimAnwar: In that case get a good C book and learn by the book. We are not a tutoring site.

Comment: @Weather Vane I would rather advice to use same for variables ,literals and functions :). Sometimes floats are still in use - for example in the embedded systems where microcontrollers have 32bit float FPUs.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I didn't know about "Code Review" .

Comment: @FahimAnwar: Now you do!

Comment: @FahimAnwar the only way to move forwards in the world of coding is by self motivation and a keen interest along with a refusal to accept defeat.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You should also perform research, study, and read books. Good intentions alone are wildly insufficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit presumably you mean "one" not WV in particular? My remark was not intended to be a definitive solution, but a reponse to having a poor teacher.

Comment: @PeterJ an embedded target would qualify as a "good reason" not to use `double`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes.

Comment: @Weather Vane I just gave you the example - and if you are not involved in the embedded world - it is a huge part of the programming world, as we have more and more embedded stuff around us. Nowadays even £1.5 micros have the FPU :) My comment was mainly about having same type functions, literals & variables to avoid unnecessary casts - which take processor time and degrade precision of the calculations

Comment: @PeterJ I certainly was very much involved in the embedded world, more than PCs whose use was mainly as a tool. But as a parallel, I don't use `short` because `int` is "too big". I would use it for a very good reason.

Comment: @Weather Vane ??? on uC with 32bit FPU if you want to use the hardware for real number calculations you must use floats not because double are "too big" but because otherwise you will use the software implementation. for example on STM32F7 which FPU is 64bit I will use double numbers. Same is with ints. On 32 bit systems using 16 or 8 bit ones may cause some overhead.

Comment: @PeterJ I think we are at cross-purposes. I never suggested using `double` on a uC which naturally handles `float`.

Comment: So I do not understand you int / short example

Comment: @PeterJ if the natural sized types are `double` and `int`, I would only use `float` or `short` for very good reasons. I was making an analogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could start by dropping `else if ( val1 == val2 )` for just `else`, since it's the only case left, and you will avoid floating point equality error at worst and at best simplify your code a little bit.

But the real culprit is this line:

```
result = pow( val1 + val2 , 3/4 ) ;
```

`3/4` is `0` because of *integer division*. Use `3.0/4` for instance or just `0.75`.

Comment: You could also use a type cast. Like `(float)3/4 `.

Comment: I would suggest double instead of float as you use double literals & functions

Comment: `0.75` is a double already. If you want a `float`, you need `0.75f`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre literals are double, functions are double but variables are float :)